# How to get the data and count null and non-null values in sql of multiple columns specific dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help to get the data and count null and non-null values in sql of multiple columns specific dates in a table. I know how to do it get the all values of null and non-null of specific dates in single query separated as below , but I don't know how to incorporate it with all columns with values of null and non-null counted in one single query.

```
SELECT 
    RECEIPTKEY,
    RECEIPTDATE,
    CLOSEDDATE,
    VERIFIEDCLOSEDDATE,
    ArrivalDateTime,
    ACTUALDEPARTUREDATE,
    DOOR,
    SUSR1,
    SUSR4,
    SUSR5,
    SHIPFROMCITY,
    CARRIERKEY,
    DriverName,
    TrailerNumber,
    TrailerOwner,
    TEMPERATURE,
    ADDDATE,
    ADDWHO
FROM
    wmwhse1.RECEIPT
WHERE
    ADDDATE BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2022-09-30'
ORDER BY ADDDATE DESC
```

Now I need to extract values of null and non-null values and count them of specific dates

What's the query to get this result?

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and add some datat to the table, to see what is null and what not

Comment: Are you looking to count the number of 'null' and 'not null' values returned by a specific column in your query?

Comment: @justin Yes I need to count the number of 'null' and 'not null' values returned by a specific column .Thanks

Comment: @MousaAlkadi - Understood, I posted an answer that fits your description of the problem

Answer (score 0):

SUM() can be used in MYSQL count the `null` values and `not null` values of each specific column

**Example; to count the `null` values:**

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(COLUMN NAME) as 'COLUMN NAME null count' From SCHEMANAME.TABLE where CONDITIONS...
```

To get the `NOT null` values, simply add an `!` to the front of `ISNULL` to reverse its meaning.

**Example:**
`SUM(!ISNULL(COLUMN NAME)`

In your case, if you want to count the number of null and not null values of every column you listed within the specified date range, it's a bit repetitive, but the following query will get you the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ISNULL(RECEIPTKEY)) as 'RECEIPTKEY null count',
    SUM(!ISNULL(RECEIPTKEY)) as 'RECEIPTKEY NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(RECEIPTDATE)) AS 'RECEIPTDATE null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(RECEIPTDATE)) AS 'RECEIPTDATE NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(CLOSEDDATE)) AS 'CLOSEDDATE null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(CLOSEDDATE)) AS 'CLOSEDDATE NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(VERIFIEDCLOSEDDATE)) AS 'VERIFIEDCLOSEDDATE null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(VERIFIEDCLOSEDDATE)) AS 'VERIFIEDCLOSEDDATE NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(ArrivalDateTime)) AS 'ArrivalDateTime null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(ArrivalDateTime)) AS 'ArrivalDateTime NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(ACTUALDEPARTUREDATE)) AS 'ACTUALDEPARTUREDATE null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(ACTUALDEPARTUREDATE)) AS 'ACTUALDEPARTUREDATE NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(DOOR)) AS 'DOOR null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(DOOR)) AS 'DOOR NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(SUSR1)) AS 'SUSR1 null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(SUSR1)) AS 'SUSR1 NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(SUSR4)) AS 'SUSR4 null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(SUSR4)) AS 'SUSR4 NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(SUSR5)) AS 'SUSR5 null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(SUSR5)) AS 'SUSR5 NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(SHIPFROMCITY)) AS 'SHIPFROMCITY null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(SHIPFROMCITY)) AS 'SHIPFROMCITY NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(CARRIERKEY)) AS 'CARRIERKEY null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(CARRIERKEY)) AS 'CARRIERKEY NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(DriverName)) AS 'DriverName null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(DriverName)) AS 'DriverName NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(TrailerNumber)) AS 'TrailerNumber null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(TrailerNumber)) AS 'TrailerNumber NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(TrailerOwner)) AS 'TrailerOwner null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(TrailerOwner)) AS 'TrailerOwner NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(TEMPERATURE)) AS 'TEMPERATURE null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(TEMPERATURE)) AS 'TEMPERATURE NOT null count',
    SUM(ISNULL(ADDWHO)) AS 'ADDWHO null count',
    SUM(! ISNULL(ADDWHO)) AS 'ADDWHO NOT null count'
FROM
    wmwhse1.RECEIPT
WHERE
    ADDDATE BETWEEN '2021-09-01' AND '2022-09-30'
ORDER BY ADDDATE DESC
```

Note: I did not include the `ADDDATE` column in the `SELECT` clause, since the `where` clause of this query could never yield a `null` result for that column. It's also noteworthy that a `Primary Key` column will never allow null values, so there really isn't any reason to include those in such a query either.

If the `ADDDATE` `null` values are also needed, you will want to do that as a separate query because there is no guarantee that the `null` values occurred during the date range specified. The `Where` clause of such a query would be this:

```
WHERE ADDDATE is null
```